# Ejecutar varias consultas preparadas

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta en la cual en el **while** de dicha consulta hago otra subconsulta pero no trae nada.

**¿Podrían ver que esta mal en el código que no trae nada?** De hecho no pasa por el primer while.

```
 function datos(){

 $opcion=$this->opcion;
 $fila="";
 $dias="";
 if ($opcion=="todo") {
  echo "entre al if";
   $sql="SELECT count(e.RUT_PARTICIPANTE) as cantidad,cg.NOMBRE_CURSO,cg.COSTO,cu.ID_CURSO_UNICO,cu.DURACION_H,cu.JORNADA_H,
          cu.CANTIDAD_PARTICIPANTES,cu.fecha_inicio,cu.fecha_termino,cu.HORA_DESDE,cu.HORA_HASTA,c.nombre_comuna,cu.RUT_RELATOR,nombre_estado
          from  participanes p, enrolamiento e,curso_unico cu,curso_generico cg,comunas c,estado_curso ec
          where p.RUT_PARTICIPANTE=e.RUT_PARTICIPANTE
          AND   c.id_comuna=cu.id_comuna
          AND   cg.ID_CURSO=cu.ID_CURSO
          AND   cu.ID_CURSO_UNICO=e.ID_CURSO_UNICO
          AND ec.id_estado_curso=cu.id_estado_curso";
          $stmt=$this->conexion->prepare($sql);
          if (!$stmt) {
            echo $this->conexion->error;
          }
          $stmt->bind_result($cantidad,$n_curso,$costo,$id_curso,$duracion,$jornada,$can_part,$f_inicio,$f_termino,$h_desde,$h_hasta,$comuna,$relator,$estado);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result(); 
          $stmt->free_result();



          while($stmt->fetch()){

            $stmt1=$this->conexion->prepare("SELECT d.nombre FROM curso_dias cd, dias d where cd.num_dia=d.num_dia and cd.ID_CURSO_UNICO=?");
            if (!$stmt1) {
              echo $this->conexion->error;
            }
            $stmt1->bind_param('i',$id_curso);
            $stmt1->bind_result($nombre);
            $stmt1->execute();
             $stmt1->store_result();
            while ($stmt1->execute()) {
            $dias="$nombre,";

            }
            $stmt1->close();
            $horario=$dias."<br>desde:$h_desde hasta:$h_hasta";
           $fila.="<tr>
                   <td>$id_curso</td>
                   <td>$relator</td>
                   <td>$duracion</td>
                   <td>$jornada</td>
                   <td>$$cant_part</td>
                   <td>$f_inicio</td>
                   <td>$$f_termino</td>
                   <td>$horario</td>
                    <td>$estado</td>
                  </tr>";
            $dias="";
            echo $id_curso;   
          }
          $stmt->close();

 }

 return $fila;
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a realizar un `var_dump($stmt)` para ver si está devolviendo resultados o no?

Comment: @David probare eso

Comment: @David me sale esto que significa                    object(mysqli_stmt)[7]
  public 'affected_rows' => null
  public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'param_count' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'errno' => null
  public 'error' => null
  public 'error_list' => null
  public 'sqlstate' => null
  public 'id' => null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que [estás liberando los recursos y memoria asociados con el almacenamiento del resultado con `$stmt->free_result()`](http://php.net/mysqli-result.free) antes de hacer uso de dichos datos:

> **Nota:**
>
> Siempre se debe liberar el resultado con mysqli_free_result(), cuando
>   el objeto del resultado ya no es necesario.

Además, deberías hacer el [`bind_result()` después del `execute()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-result) y el `store_result()` antes del `bind_result()`:

> **Nota:**
>
> Observe que todas las columnas deben ser vinculadas después de
>   llamar a mysqli_stmt_execute() y antes de llamar a
>   mysqli_stmt_fetch(). Dependiendo de los tipos de columna las variables
>   pueden cambiar silenciosamente al tipo de PHP correspondiente.

La forma correcta de usar `free_result()` sería al finalizar el trabajo con los registros obtenidos, que podría ser tras obtener todos con un `fetch_all` o al finalizar el bucle `while`.

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo usar la primera consulta, usarla y liberarla posteriormente:

```
 function datos(){

 $opcion=$this->opcion;
 $fila="";
 $dias="";
 if ($opcion=="todo") {
  echo "entre al if";
   $sql="SELECT count(e.RUT_PARTICIPANTE) as cantidad,cg.NOMBRE_CURSO,cg.COSTO,cu.ID_CURSO_UNICO,cu.DURACION_H,cu.JORNADA_H,
          cu.CANTIDAD_PARTICIPANTES,cu.fecha_inicio,cu.fecha_termino,cu.HORA_DESDE,cu.HORA_HASTA,c.nombre_comuna,cu.RUT_RELATOR,nombre_estado
          from  participanes p, enrolamiento e,curso_unico cu,curso_generico cg,comunas c,estado_curso ec
          where p.RUT_PARTICIPANTE=e.RUT_PARTICIPANTE
          AND   c.id_comuna=cu.id_comuna
          AND   cg.ID_CURSO=cu.ID_CURSO
          AND   cu.ID_CURSO_UNICO=e.ID_CURSO_UNICO
          AND ec.id_estado_curso=cu.id_estado_curso";
          $stmt=$this->conexion->prepare($sql);
          if (!$stmt) {
            echo $this->conexion->error;
          }
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result(); 
          $stmt->bind_result($cantidad, $n_curso, $costo, $id_curso,
               $duracion, $jornada, $can_part, $f_inicio, $f_termino,
               $h_desde, $h_hasta, $comuna, $relator, $estado);



          while($stmt->fetch()){

            $stmt1=$this->conexion->prepare("SELECT d.nombre FROM curso_dias cd, dias d where cd.num_dia=d.num_dia and cd.ID_CURSO_UNICO=?");
            if (!$stmt1) {
              echo $this->conexion->error;
            }
            $stmt1->bind_param('i',$id_curso);
            $stmt1->execute();
            /* Una forma tosca de hacerlo ...
            $stmt1->store_result();
            $stmt1->bind_result($nombre);
            $dias = []; // o $dias = array(); si usas una versión antigua de PHP
            while ($stmt1->fetch()) {
                 $dias[] = $nombre;
            }
            $dias = implode(',', $dias); */
            /* La forma que te propongo: */
            $res = $stmt1->get_result();
            $dias = implode(',', $res->fetch_all());
            $stmt1->close();
            $horario=$dias."<br>desde:$h_desde hasta:$h_hasta";
           $fila.="<tr>
                   <td>$id_curso</td>
                   <td>$relator</td>
                   <td>$duracion</td>
                   <td>$jornada</td>
                   <td>$$cant_part</td>
                   <td>$f_inicio</td>
                   <td>$$f_termino</td>
                   <td>$horario</td>
                    <td>$estado</td>
                  </tr>";
            $dias="";
            echo $id_curso;   
          }
          $stmt->free_result();
          /* Esto es un alias del anterior: $stmt->close(); */

 }

 return $fila;
}
```

Yo, personalmente, prefiero obtener fila a fila o todos los resultados a una variable y trabajar con esos datos, no me gusta dejar que algo modifique variables y arriesgarme a provocar efectos laterales.

Nota: en el `while` interior estás haciendo `while ($stmt1->execute())`. ¿no sería `$stmt1->fetch()`? Te he hecho unos cambios para que los revises, quizá sea la mejor forma de hacer lo que intentas.

Comment: no reconoce la funcion fetch_all() puede ser por la version de php, tengo la version 5.4.3

Comment: ¿Qué versión usas? Está soportado desde 5.3 (en la documentación pone PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7). Aún así, ¿qué me dices del resto de propuestas? Puedes usar la parte comentada o la del `fetch_all()`, como quieras.

Comment: es que yo tome el modo tosco que recomendaste y lo hice asi

Comment: Dime el error que te sale.

Comment: asi lo hice pero queda en un loop infinito $datos=array();
              while ($row=$stmt->fetch()) {
                $datos[]=$row;
              }
              $stmt->free_result();
              //luego recorro
              while ($datos) {
                echo $datos["id_curso"];

                //aca ejecuto la  segunda consulta preparada
              }

Comment: esta bien lo que hice ?

Comment: ejecute el codigo que dejaste escrito pero aparece el error Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all() in line 312 que seria esto  $dias = implode(',', $stmt1->fetch_all());

Comment: Estoy en el móvil, no puedo copiar y editar tu código, en breve te digo dónde está el error, no se le parece mucho ese código al que puse..

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58216/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-jose-miguel-jara).

Comment: ahora ejecute el codigo que me diste y funciono pero en los dias me trae repetido martes,miercoles,martes,miercoles,   la otra duda que tengo es como funciono el codigo si se supone que no se puede ejecutar dos consultas al mismo tiempo ya que la segunda consulta preparada se ejecuta y la primera todavia no se cierra

Comment: tengo otra duda por ejemplo si en la segunda consulta lo quiero guardar en una variable y no en un array se hace de la misma manera

Comment: Esa es la función de `store_result()`. ¿Seguimos por el chat o por aquí?

Comment: Lo estoy guardando en una variable, pero uso `implode()` para que sólo haya un separador coma entre elementos, con tu código original se quedaba una coma de más al final.

Comment: Si no quieres que se repitan los días deberías usar `UNIQUE`, `DISTINCT` o `GROUP BY` / `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: el primer while se ejecuta una vez parece ya que yo tengo dos filas de datos pero me muestra una